# Data in two databases, eager spool resulting in query

Tags: sql-server-2005, performance

I have two databases in SQL2k5: one that holds a large amount of static data (SQL Database 1) (never updated but frequently inserted into) and one that holds relational data (SQL Database 2) related to the static data.  They're separated mainly because of corporate guidelines and business requirements: assume for the following problem that combining them is not practical.

There are places in SQLDB2 that PKs in SQLDB1 are referenced; triggers control the referential integrity, since cross-database relationships are troublesome in SQL Server.  BUT, because of the large amount of data in SQLDB1, I'm getting eager spools on queries that join from the Id in SQLDB2 that references the data in SQLDB1. (With me so far? Maybe an example will help:)

```
SELECT t.Id, t.Name, t2.Company 
FROM SQLDB1.table t INNER JOIN SQLDB2.table t2 ON t.Id = t2.FKId
```

This query results in a eager spool that's 84% of the load of the query; the table in SQLDB1 has 35M rows, so it's completely choking this query.  I can't create a view on the table in SQLDB1 and use that as my FK/index; it doesn't want me to create a constraint based on a view.

Anyone have any idea how I can fix this huge bottleneck? (Short of putting the static data in the first db: believe me, I've argued that one until I'm blue in the face to no avail.)

Thanks!

valkyrie

Edit: also can't create an indexed view because you can't put schemabinding on a view that references a table outside the database where the view resides.  Dang it.

Edit 2: adding in index hints made zero difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else runs into this problem, I don't have a great solution. But what I ended up having to do was put some limited dupe data into the target database, in order to completely bypass the eager spool.